# PHP automatically redirecting to another page

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect, hyperlink

I am making a login system. When I press the `log out` link, it redirects to the `log_out.php` and instantly redirects to the `log_in.php`.

Here is the page with the link:

```php
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo '<li class="right"><a href="log_out.php">Log out</a></li>';

        session_start();
        $name = $_SESSION["username"];
        echo "You are $name.";
        ?>

        <button onclick='window.location.assign("change_password.php")'>Change your password</button>
        <button onclick='window.location.assign("delete_account.php")'>Delete this account</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is `log_out.php`:

```php
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
?>
```

It didn't change even when I deleted everything from `log_out.php`.
When I copy the address and go to the page, It also redirects.

Please help me. I am desperate. Thanks for answer.

Comment: Do you have some code that gets included everywhere that checks for login status and if not logged in redirects to the login page?

Comment: No, I have just this code

Comment: There is nothing in the question emitting a redirect. `When I copy the address and go to the page, It also redirects.` please edit the question to demonstrate that - preferably with a curl call